# XSD: Default value of complex type as string

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have an xsd schema like:

```
<xs:element name="employee" type="personinfo"/>
<xs:complexType name="personinfo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It works perfectly if there is no problem with data processing:

```
<employee>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>
```

But if data processing fails, then data does come like:

```
<employee> Data not found </employee>
```

And this is valid as well. My query is if I can give any default string value to my schema definition, like:

```
<xs:element name="employee" type="personinfo" default="Data not found"/>
```

Or is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mixed="true"` if you have mixed data-types. You expected the following,

```
<xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="firstname" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastname" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I found it using the following strategy, generating *.xsd using following xml data.

```
<employees>
<employee>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>

<employee>
data not found
</employee>
</employees>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP, did you try it?